# How can I improve my Windows Batch File that merges two PDFs into a separate folder to move the PDF regardless of whether a merge exists

Tags: windows, batch, pdf, merge

I have a windows batch file that merges PDFs from two separate folders and dumps them into a 3rd folder. One of the PDFs is a PDF of a map survey and the other are any accompanying photos the surveyor took. As of now the batch file only moves files that it is able to merge, but I'd want the first page map survey to move to the other folder regardless of whether it has an accompanying photo.

So my question is if I can add a line that moves PDFs from the "`sourcemap`" directory in my code below regardless of whether "`sourcetables`" directory has a matching file.

Here is my code below:

```bash
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "pdffile="
set "pdfattach="

set "pdftk=C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe"
set "sourcemap=C:\GIS\Maps\Ranch Map Staging Folders\PCA\Central"

set "sourcetables=C:\GIS\Maps\Ranch Map Staging Folders\PCA\Photos"
set "destination=C:\GIS\Maps\Ranch Map Staging Folders\PCA\Central Completed"

set "gisfolder=C:\GIS\Maps\Ranch Map Staging Folders\PCA\Central Completed"
set "spfolder=\\sunpacific.local\lerdodata\Sun Pacific Public\6 - Business Units\Sun Pacific Farming Cooperative\B - General\10 - Maps\Ranch Maps\Other Maps\PCA\Maps\Central"
set "archivefolder=\\sunpacific.local\lerdodata\Sun Pacific Public\6 - Business Units\Sun Pacific Farming Cooperative\B - General\10 - Maps\Other Maps\PCA\Old Maps\Central"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /o:n "!sourcemap!\*.pdf"') do (
     set "pdffile=!sourcemap!\%%~i"
     set "pdfattach=!sourcetables!\PestManagement_TableSeries_!pdffile:~50!"
     set "outputpdf=%%~ni"
     "!pdftk!" "!pdffile!" "!pdfattach!" cat output "!destination!\!pdffile:~50,-4! - Field Scout Survey Map !date:~-4,4!!date:~-10,2!!date:~-7,2!.pdf"
     echo "Successfully completed !pdffile:~50,-4!"
    )

move "!spfolder!\*.pdf" "!archivefolder!"
move "!gisfolder!\*.pdf" "!spfolder!"

cmd /k
```

Comment: Programming is offtopic here, try stackoverflow

Comment: @Gantendo batch scripting has always been considered on topic here. https://meta.superuser.com/questions/7736/are-batch-script-questions-allowed-on-super-user

Comment: @Mokubai Wouldn't it be wise to update https://superuser.com/help/on-topic ? `it is not about …  programming and software development,`

Comment: @Gantendo why? It is not really "programing" as it is just using standard features available in every version of DOS and every subsequent version of Windows. Batch scripting is essentially just chaining `cmd.exe` commands together and putting them in a text file. It is essentially the same as using the windows terminal which is considered to be on-topic. Unless you consider using a command prompt (DOS) to be "programming" which is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @Mokubai Batch is turing complete, and scripting is a subset of programming. But even if those 2 facts wouldn't be true, we should still improve the wording to prevent confusion. Improving the wording does not have downsides afaik, not improving it clearly does

Comment: @Gantendo "turing complete"-ness is not a measure of site topicality. That you want the help page adjusted sounds like something you should take to [meta]. As it stands this is on-topic here by general community consensus.

Comment: @Gantendo If programming is off topic then why is there an option to add code?

Comment: @GeorgeBunkall The Video Production and Travel stack exchanges have the same buttons in the editor toolbar. I am pretty sure programming is offtopic on travel.stackexchange.com

Comment: @GeorgeBunkall you could add a try-catch to this to perform that move. It has been a long time since I worked in Batch. I'd probably do this in Powershell myself now, but you test for the existence of the files, and just move the one(s) that exist.

Comment: @Gantendo batch scripts and powershell are generally allowed here without issue, as they are closer to average user tools than "true" programming languages. It is more a case of they would be on topic on either site, and less a case of their only being on topic on one of them.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_pdftk=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe"
set "_date=!date:~-4,4!!date:~-10,2!!date:~-7,2!"
set "_str= - Field Scout Survey Map !_date!"

set "_tbl=C:\GIS\Maps\Ranch Map Staging Folders\PCA\Photos"
set "_map=C:\GIS\Maps\Ranch Map Staging Folders\PCA\Central"
set "_dst=C:\GIS\Maps\Ranch Map Staging Folders\PCA\Central Completed"

set "_arcDir=\\sunpacific.local\lerdodata\Sun Pacific Public\6 - Business Units\Sun Pacific Farming Cooperative\B - General\10 - Maps\Other Maps\PCA\Old Maps\Central"
set "_spDir=\\sunpacific.local\lerdodata\Sun Pacific Public\6 - Business Units\Sun Pacific Farming Cooperative\B - General\10 - Maps\Ranch Maps\Other Maps\PCA\Maps\Central"

for /f "delims=" %%i in =;(' dir /b /a-d /o:n "!_map!\*.pdf" ');= do =;(
     set "_pdf=%%~dpnxi" & set "_outputpdf=%%~nxi"
     if exist "!_tbl!\PestManagement_TableSeries_!_pdf:~50!.pdf" =;(
         call set "_photo=!_tb!\PestManagement_TableSeries_!_pdf:~50!.pdf"
         call "!_pdftk!" "!_pdf!" "!_photo!" cat output "!_dst!\!_pdf:~50,-4!!_str!.pdf"
        );= else copy /y "!_pdf!" "!_dst!\!_pdf:~50,-4!!_str!.pdf"
     call set "_pdf=" & call set "_photo=" & call set "_outputpdf="
     call echo/Successfully completed: "!_pdf:~50,-4!"
    );=

2>nul =;( move /y "!_spDir!\*.pdf" "!_arcDir!" & move /y "!_dst!\*.pdf" "!_spDir!"
    );= & timeout -1 | echo/Press any key to exit... & endlocal & exit /b
```

---

Just test:

```bash
if the photo file exists so execute (
  cat command this_file_pdf + this_file_photo ...
) else cat this_file_pdf ...
```

> As OP [music2myear](https://superuser.com/users/74026/music2myear) said
> *...but you test the existence of the files*

---

Please note that some adjustment may be necessary given my language difficulty/limitation, please test and let me know the result and/or any additional adjustments...

Comment: The current code has some inconsistency, where the variable `%destination%` is equal to the variable `%gisfolder%`, and `set "outputpdf=%%~ni"` is also defined, but I didn't see use of the `outputpdf` variable...

Comment: the reason the destination and gis folders are equal are because it is intentionally a staging folder for me to audit. Thank you for your response, this is really helpful for me.

Comment: I think I need to use the `outputpdf ` variable because i'm getting a message that the system cannot find the file specified

Comment: If you are editing/changing the code, some edition compatible with your edit/change is necessary, so it would be better to edit the question adding all the changes

Comment: It occurred to me that an extension for the photos was not provided, and if these photos are already converted to pdf, if not, I'm not sure if pdftk will do the conversion when running `pdftk .. cat`